# Send message to multiple microservice (only one instance of them)

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq

I use spring boot.
We have a few microservice, each of then have many instance.
I was  thinking using a messaging software like ibm mq.

I saw there is a starter.
https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring

if microservice x sent an event x.created.

I would like y and z get it... but only one instance of y and z.

I begin, but I think for doing that I will need to send message to two queue

Comment: We are using Kafka for same purpose. And Kafka has a grouping mechanism. You can group y instances and z instances separately. So this way only once instance of y and z gets the message. Maybe ibm mq also has the same thing

Comment: You can do that with pub sub with MQ - you can have the publisher x publish to topic name X and subscribers y and z get subscriptions?
If only two subscribers, don't need to make it any more complicated than that. 
Samples for JMS pub sub [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns)

Comment: work only if there is only one instance of y or z.... because there are many instance of y and z, i don't want all of then receive it...

Comment: Hi, old thread, but did anyone find a solution to this? Multiple instances of the same consumer, but only one receives the message, from a topic, not a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka seems to be one of the available options here.

When you send a message via producer to a kafka-topic, all the consumer group subscribed to the particular topic will receive the message and the consumer group can have any number of consumers in it and only one consumer will receive the message.